# Continuity of two variables function using polar coordinates

Tags: functions, trigonometry, continuity, polar-coordinates, several-complex-variables

Consider the function 
$$
f(x,y) = 
\begin{cases} 
\displaystyle{\frac{\sin (x-y)}{|x|+|y|}} &\mbox{ if } (x,y)\not=(0,0), \\ 
0 &\mbox{ if } (x,y)=(0,0).  
\end{cases}
$$

I was asked to check the continuity of the function at the origin, so I think I need to use method of polar coordinate, where $x= r \sin \theta$ and $y = r \cos \theta$, and substitute it into the equation.

But after trying to simplify it, I found that the $r$ in the bottom cannot be cancelled out, and I know $r$ will tends to $0$ as $(x, y)$ tends to $0$. So $r$ must be cancelled out in the denominator.

Is there some trigonometric functions that can be applied so that the $r$ in the nominator can be taken out as common factor and is cancelled out with the $r$ in the denominator?

Answer (score 2):

The function $f$ is not continuous at the origin. 
Consider the path $y=0$. 
Then 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+ } \frac{\sin x}{|x|} 
=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+ } \frac{\sin x}{x} 
= 1 
$$
while 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^- } \frac{\sin x}{|x|} 
= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^- } \frac{\sin x}{-x} 
= -1.  
$$

Comment: much thanks in answering my query :)